# Может с shell script возратить (return) какое-то значение?

Tags: java, shell

Я новичок в `.sh`, но я понял, что нет возможности возвращать значение таким образом, как в Java. Есть ли возможность "обмениваться" значениями между скриптами?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете запускать свой *.sh скрипт из Java и получить по итогам его выполнения код возврата, например:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -n 1 -w 100 127.0.0.1");
int res = p.waitFor();
```

Также вы можете получить ссылки на error/input/output стримы используя соответствующие методы класса [Process](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html) и использовать их для обмена данными.

Comment: Я уже выполнял такого рода действия из python. К сожалению программы не выполняться так как я этого хочу и я решил полностью перейти на shell скрипты.

Comment: Опишите, что конкретно не выполняется. Какие вы задачи хотите решить.

Comment: Я хочу скачать картинки графиков из grafana. Для этого я создал python прогу которая зачитывает из фалов аргументы для скачки и потом мне нужен "curl" из shell. Сначала я пыталася сделать это с subprocess в питоне, потом 3мя разными способами пытался вызвать скрипт из питона. передача переменных, генерирование ссылкок все правильное. Делал кучу тестов на разных этарпах. Пришел к тому что если захаркодить в shell правильные команды, то все работает и скачиваеться картинка, но если (тот же самый скрипт!!!) вызвать из питона, то выдается ощибка 400 от браузера и никакой картинки

Comment: Поэтому я решил не комбинировать питон и шэлл и собирался сделать все в шэлле.

Comment: @S.G. если вам нужно скаачать файлы, то проще это сделать из языка, нежели вызывать курл из шелла